# How to use requires to return constructor functions that have dependencies

Tags: requirejs, durandal, durandal-2.0

How do you correctly use `Require.js` to load a module that returns a constructor function that has require dependencies?

My problem seems to be a scope issue, I have seen some modules that are available within the returned constructor like "durandal/app" and I dont see how they are scoped any different than the modules I have defined.

This example is modified from Durandal Creating a Module [docs](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module/)

```
define([**someothermodule**, "durandal/app"], function(**someothermodule**, app){
var backend = function(username, password){  
    this.username = username;  
    this.password = password;  
    someothermodule.whatever(); <--someothermodule is not defined
    app.whatever(); <-- this is in scope
};

backend.prototype.getCustomers = function(){
    //do some ajax and return a promise
};
return backend;
```

});

define([backend], function(backend){

```
return {
    customers:ko.observableArray([]),
    activate:function(){
        var that = this;
        var service = new backend('username', 'password');

        return service.getCustomers().then(function(results){
            that.customers(results);
        });
    }
};
```

});

Someothermodule:

```
define([], function(){

var whatever = function(){
    alert("whatever");
};

return {
    whatever: whatever
};
```

});

Comment: How's `someothermodule` look like?

Comment: Added someothermodule to the orginal post

Comment: seems to be OK. check the browser console for other errors . Do you see any error while loading someOtherModule.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index in the example above has two issues. a) in define `[backend]` is used instead of `['backend']` and b) `ko` is used without defining it. Both probably copy/paste errors.

Assuming that **someothermodule** lives in the same directory as index.js it's sufficient to define it like

```
define(['./someothermodule', ...], function( someothermodule, ... )
```

Here's the complete example:

#### backend.js

```
/*globals define*/
define(['./someothermodule', 'durandal/app', 'jquery'], function( someothermodule, app, $ ) {
    "use strict";
    var backend = function( username, password ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.whatever = someothermodule.whatever();
        app.trigger('whatever', this.whatever);
    };

    backend.prototype.getCustomers = function() {
        //do some ajax and return a promise
        return $.getJSON('app/so/19551060/fixtures/customer.json');
    };
    return backend;
});
```

#### someothermodule.js

```
/*globals define*/
define(function(){
    "use strict";
    var whatever = function(){
        return 'whatever return value';
    };

    return {
        whatever: whatever
    };
});
```

#### index.js

```
/*globals define*/
define(['./backend', 'knockout'], function(backend, ko){
    "use strict";
    return {
        customers:ko.observableArray([]),
        activate:function(){
            var that = this;
            var service = new backend('username', 'password');

            return service.getCustomers().then(function(results){
                that.customers(results);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Live version available at: http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#so/19551060

Comment: Your right, it does work, I must of fixed a script error or something because it working in my project now.  Thanks for the help.